# How to Disable NSDictionary Sort automatically key wise

Tags: iphone, ipad

When I add values in `NSMutableDictionary` it automatically set Key wise. How can i disable it and arrange as per first set first and second set second.

```
NSMutableDictionary* filteredDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[filteredDictionary setObject:@"abc" forKey:@"1"];
[filteredDictionary setObject:@"abc" forKey:@"3"];
[filteredDictionary setObject:@"abc" forKey:@"2"];
[filteredDictionary setObject:@"abc" forKey:@"5"];
[filteredDictionary setObject:@"abc" forKey:@"4"];

NSLog(@"%@",filteredDictionary);

current output:
{
1 = abc;
2 = abc;
3 = abc;
4 = abc;
5 = abc;    
}

but i want 
{
1 = abc;
3 = abc;
2 = abc;
5 = abc;    
4 = abc;
}
```

Is there any way to disable sorting as per key?

Comment: I know this is the genuine issue with Dictionary.But I can help you with alternate way of doing this. Also, there will be minor changes in accessing the values.Also, I don't understand what is the issue you are facing because of this,after all you need to access them by KeyValue only.

Comment: @amitrajput yes that's the point

Comment: It only sorts the keys when outputting the description string, it doesn't change the memory layout which is based on a hash table. If you enumerate through it, it won't be sorted as it's meant to give you fast access.

Comment: @VikasRajput   I don't want to sort dictionary but what i want is the output, in a way, such that, the way i add keys to dictionary will give me the same order in output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way of doing it:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"key" ascending:YES comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {

    if (obj1 > obj2) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    if (obj1 < obj2) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];

NSArray *sortedKeys = [[filteredDictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

NSMutableDictionary *orderedDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSString *index in sortedKeys) {
    [orderedDictionary setObject:[filteredDictionary objectForKey:index] forKey:index];
}

filteredDictionary = orderedDictionary;
```

Comment: This code fails to compile as there is no `addObject` method available  in [NSMutableDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html), wondering how it worked for OP.

Comment: Wow, I must have been on crack when I wrote that... I'll fix it! Thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 4):

`NSDictionary` isn't sorting your keys, the order of keys in a dictionary is *not defined* since it's an unordered collection.

That means that you can't trust the order of the elements when you fetch/print them unless you use `keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:` or `keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:` to sort them while fetching them.

You can also see this in the manual of [allKeys](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/allKeys);

> Return Value
>   A new array containing the dictionary’s keys, or an empty array if the
>   dictionary has no entries.
>
> Discussion
>   The order of the elements in the array is **not defined.**

There is no way to keep keys/values ordered as you want in an `NSDictionary`, so if you need them ordered in the same order as they're added, you basically have two options;

- Add them to/remove them from an ordered collection - such as an `NSArray` - at the same time as you add them to the `NSDictionary`, and use *that* collection for the ordered access.
- Add a field to the data you're adding to the dictionary that counts up for every add, then use that field with `keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:` to order it when fetching all keys from the array.

Answer (score 1):

`NSDictionary` is not meant to be sorted. You can get it sorted by getting all keys using `allKeys` and sorting that array to your liking. Then loop through this array and get the corresponding values.

Comment: but how if you know please tell me.

Comment: See the posts by Joachim and Simon.

Answer (score 1):

In `NSDictionary`  you will not get the data as you are inserting.
You can use array if you want to get data according to the data you are inserting,