# sort on nsdictionary is giving different result than sort on nsarray

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray, nsdictionary

2 days ago I asked the question how to sort elements by second word in string object and

i got solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943714/sort-nsarray-by-second-word-by-surname-in-firstname-surname-kind-of-strings)

but now I stuck into new issue

Consider I have

nsarray with--> names and

nsdictionary with same-->names(of nsarray) as value and email id as key

And my **nsarray contains**

```
   "Test Teacher"

   "Anonymous"

   "Dok Teacher"
```

and my **nsdictionary contains**

```
   "Dok Teacher" --"a@g.com"

   "Anonymous" --  "b@g.com"

   "Test Teacher" --"c@g.com"
```

As I was needed to sort these array and dictionary i sorted them using method given in link above

but after sorting I am getting data as follow

**nsarray after sorting** on second word

```
   "Anonymous"

   "Test Teacher"

   "Dok Teacher"
```

**nsdictionary after sorting** on second word of values

```
   "Anonymous" --  "b@g.com"

   "Dok Teacher" --"a@g.com"

   "Test Teacher" --"c@g.com"
```

why so  Dok Teacher and Test Teacher at different postions in dictionary and in nsarray, after using same method for sorting.

And how to get them in same order for array and dictionary.

code for sorting nsarray:

```
NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[teachersNames sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        NSString *firstTeacher2ndWord = [[[((NSString*)a) componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:1] lowercaseString];
        NSString *secondTeacher2ndWord = [[[((NSString*)b) componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:1] lowercaseString];
        return [firstTeacher2ndWord compare:secondTeacher2ndWord];
    }]];

    NSLog(@"After %@",sortedArray);

    teachersSrc=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:sortedArray];
```

code for sorting nsdictionary

```
    myArray = [teachersList keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        NSString *firstTeacher2ndWord = [[[((NSString*)a) componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:1] lowercaseString];
        NSString *secondTeacher2ndWord = [[[((NSString*)b) componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:1] lowercaseString];
        return [firstTeacher2ndWord compare:secondTeacher2ndWord];
    }];

    NSLog(@"After %@",myArray);
```

**EDIT:**

i have also tried sorting on first name for both array and dictionary and then sorting on last name for both , but its not working at all,

Comment: Edit your question with proper indention.

Comment: why you are maintaining two deferent set, array and dictionary?

Comment: because I want names to be in sorted array, when I sort nsarray the sorted order persists in nsarray but it does not persist in nsdictionary.

Comment: Consider switching to some model class as with [NSDictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12727319/696134) has problem with sorting  stuff. Create Teacher model class add properties like `Name` and `Email` than it would be pretty easy to do sorting, may be this sounds rash as you may need to change code at all place in your project, its the approach I can suggest you for now.

Comment: based on the link you have provided and your answer, the difference is in your end you are sorting by key, while on the answer he was sorting it by the value of the dictionary

Comment: @Virendra, Did you use sortedArrayUsingComparator for sorting. I have update the answer. Please follow??

Comment: @Janak NSMutableDictionary does not have any `sorting problems` at all! It is an unordered collection so you just cannot sort it. Full stop. ;) If you need something ordered use an ordered collection (e.g. NS[Mutable]Array).

Comment: @Joshua because i wanted both email ids and names in sorted manner

Comment: dictionaries cannot be sorted.

Comment: yes, but we can get items in sorted mannner from dictionary by using function "keysSortedByValueUsingComparator"

Comment: @HAS and how will he store details in NSMutableArray ? key/values ? Please feel free to answer if you feel you have the solution to OP's question.

Comment: @JanakNirmal There a many different possibilities, I'll give you two of them: You can create a custom class to store all your object's properties (e.g. `firstName`, `lastName`, `emailAddress`) and put those into an array. You can then sort the array using the key (=property) zoo want and always have a sorted array. The other possibility is to use an `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries` where the dictionaries contain all the properties you need. After that you can sort the array. I prefer using custom classes (first approach), but whatever you do, your "outer datasource object" should be an `NSArray`.

Comment: @HAS so alternative 1 I already suggested, alternative 2 OP is already doing that ? nothing new....lets conclude this debate here as OP has got his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have this:

```
 NSArray *array = @[@"Test Teacher",@"Anonymous",@"Dok Teacher"];
 NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"a@g.com":@"Dok Teacher",@"b@g.com":@"Anonymous",@"c@g.com":@"Test Teacher"};


//sort the array first
    NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSString *firstTeacher2ndWord  =[[(NSString *)obj1 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]lastObject];
     NSString *secondTeacher2ndWord =[[(NSString *)obj2 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]lastObject];


    if([firstTeacher2ndWord compare:secondTeacher2ndWord options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == FALSE){ // means they are the same
        //compare full text
        firstTeacher2ndWord = (NSString *)obj1;
        secondTeacher2ndWord = (NSString *)obj2;
    }

    return [firstTeacher2ndWord compare:secondTeacher2ndWord options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
}];

 NSLog(@"Sorted Array %@",sortedArray);

//sort the dictionary key using values
    NSArray *sortedDictionaryKey =[dictionary keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
      NSString *firstTeacher2ndWord  =[[(NSString *)obj1 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]lastObject];
     NSString *secondTeacher2ndWord =[[(NSString *)obj2 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]lastObject];


    if([firstTeacher2ndWord compare:secondTeacher2ndWord options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == FALSE){ // means they are the same
        //compare full text
        firstTeacher2ndWord = (NSString *)obj1;
        secondTeacher2ndWord = (NSString *)obj2;
    }


    return [firstTeacher2ndWord compare:secondTeacher2ndWord options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]
}];

//get the values from the dictionary based on the sorted keys
 NSLog(@"Sorted Dictionary %@",[dictionary objectsForKeys:sortedDictionaryKey notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]]);
```

will give you this output:

```
//Sorted Array
Sorted Array(
Anonymous,
"Dok Teacher",
"Test Teacher"
)

//Sorted Dictionary
Sorted Dictionary(
    Anonymous,
    "Dok Teacher",
    "Test Teacher"
  )
```

Comment: have you used 2nd word (i.e. "Teacher" in case of DOK , Test) for sorting, if yes where are you getting it? like in my case objectAtIndex:2

Comment: @VirendraRavalji you mean you only sort the entry by the 2nd word? and if they are the same thats the only time you will compare the whole word? is that correct?

Comment: ya partially correct, because yet i have not written code to consider full name or full string

Comment: because the code i provided compares the whole string without case sensitivity

Comment: hmm , but full name only then , when surname or 2nd word is same

Comment: @VirendraRavalji updated my code maybe you can check. basically it will get the 2nd word and compare it. if they are the same, it will compare the full text

Comment: I have simplified it a little bit

Answer (score 0):

First the value array of The dictionary(teachersList) is unsorted and you don't know how the element in are arranged.

Second `Dok Teacher` and `Test Teacher` is the same on the second word, there is no order between them, the order of them after sorting is depended on the sorting method(stable or unstable) and the order of the original array.

If elements in the value array have the same order in `teachersNames`, the result will be the same. Otherwise the order of `Dok Teacher` and `Test Teacher` is undefined.

**Note: value array here is `teachersList.allValues`**

Comment: ya correct but then how to make them in same order, i have also tried sorting on first name for both array and dictionary and then sorting on last name for both , but its not working at all, How to solve this?

Comment: @VirendraRavalji If you want they have the same order, you must make sure the key you used for sorting is unique. So I think you should sort on name neither last name nor first name.

Comment: i would like to but its requirment by client

Comment: @VirendraRavalji So what is your requirement of client?

Comment: @VirendraRavalji It's ok, but why do you sort the `teachersList. If you want result of sorting array and dictionary to be same, just use result of sorted teachersNames, why do you need to sort on the dictionary.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44855/discussion-between-virendra-ravalji-and-kudocc)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is second name `Teacher` contains in two words. So when you sort the same in array. It will sort the name alphabetically. Since the second name are same for two words. So it will not reflect in the output. But if you change the order then you can see the expected output. I have implemented the code for sorting an array below:-

When execute this code below you will get the output:-

```
  NSArray *array1=@[@"Test Teacher",@"Anonymous",@"Dok Teacher"];
NSArray *sortedArray=[array1 sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
}];
NSLog(@"%@",sortedArray);
```

Output:-

```
 Anonymous,
 "Dok Teacher",
 "Test Teacher"
```

Comment: by my sorting priority is only Last Name i.e Teacher in this case, I think you have considered whole name

Comment: @virendra, I have sorted only array name which you wanted in the ouput.

Comment: have you read my complete question , ya I will get output like this if   I sort on first name(first word i.e Dok, Test in this case), but when i sorted them on second name(i.e Teacher in this case) I am not getting this order. Look my code three is "objectAtIndex:2"

Comment: Sorry Virendra, Still i am not clear. But why you want to sort them on second name ??

Comment: ya now you get my point , i want them to sort on 2nd name because client wants the list of teacher to be sorted on surname, ya what you have done in code is correct but its sorting on first name and therfore you are getting same order for both

Comment: @Virendra,I would request, please make your output more brief. Because as you said surname, So make output with proper name. So that it is easy to rectify.

Comment: sorry for that, i will make it

Comment: @Virendra, If you change the second name then you will get the correct order of output. Since Teacher exist in two words. So if search the second name it will not reflect the order. Please follow

Comment: ya but that also the case , in which Teacher can have same surname.., or complete same name

Comment: @Virendra, If teacher can have same name and surname in this case why you required to check the second name. Better to check the complete name as have updated